# Add new record in to Hyperformula sheets take long time to calculate

Tags: reactjs

We have an application with around 5000 records on the ‘aggregation’ sheet. We also have 8 more sheets that contain some codes, each defined as named expressions. These codes are used on the aggregation sheet. These codes will be used inside the aggregation sheet on different columns as a text or inside the formula. We need to calculate the usage count for each code on each sheet and also calculate the total if the code is used in the aggregation sheet.

[image]

**Formulas**

Total

`=IF(groups!C1="","0",IF(I1="N",SUMIF(aggregations!B:B,"*" & groups!C1& "*",aggregations!K:K),SUMIF(aggregations!B:B,"*" & groups!C1& "*",aggregations!M:M)))`

Usage count

`=IF(groups!C1="","0",COUNTIFS(aggregations!B:B,"*" & groups!C1& "*"))`

It takes more than 5 seconds to build the Hyperformula instance using the ‘buildFromSheets’ method. The expected aggregation sheet could have more than 20,000 records, so the application build time is long.

Adding a record, deleting multiple recodes and update the cell value to the aggregation sheet freezes the application and takes around long time to complete the operation.

[image]

I have created a demo on CodeSandbox and looking for a help :)

https://codesandbox.io/s/pivot-budget-aggregation-rx1kzt?file=/src/components/Container.tsx